# How to host my discord bot 24/7 if i'm using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord

I made a sort of currency system in my discord bot using MongoDB (Mongoose) and it works perfectly, but I have no idea how to host the bot 24/7. Maybe I should use a VPS? Maybe I could do something in the MongoDB itself because right now I use localhost. **I'd prefer something free**, but I could try and buy something cheap.

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Product/service recommendation questions (such as where to host MongoDB) are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Also: running a service 24x7 is a fairly broad topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Repl.it to host your bot 24/7, it includes database support so once you transfer your files and everything. There's a little section about installing Mongo.

Discord.py: https://repl.it/talk/learn/Hosting-discordpy-bots-with-replit/11008

Discord.js: https://repl.it/talk/learn/Hosting-discordjs-bots-on-replit-Works-for-both-discordjs-and-Eris/11027

EDIT: And keep in mind this is all *free*.